# Delegated event handler for a set of dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My JS is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data1').change(function(){
        title = $('#title1').val();
        url = $('#url1').val();
        $.post('library/edit.php',{title:title, url:url},function(res){
            alert ("updated !");
        });
    });
});
```

and my HMTL-markup:

```
<div id="data1">
<input name="title1" type="text" id="title1" />
<input name="url1" type="text" id="url1" />
</div>
```

I wrote that code to call to a PHP file on change of textbox.
that code works as expected.

But now I've added more textboxes as follows:

```
<div id="div1"><input name="title1" type="text" id="title1" />
<input name="url1" type="text" id="url1" /></div>
<div id="div2"><input name="title2" type="text" id="title2" />
<input name="url2" type="text" id="url2" /></div>
<div id="div3"><input name="title3" type="text" id="title3" />
<input name="url3" type="text" id="url3" /></div>
```

Now I want the same functionality so that any of these textboxes works like title1 in my earlier code. So if input#title-3 is changed I want the change to be uploaded via POST to my PHP-script.

Important: The number of boxes are dynamic.

Comment: What is the question? I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: His meaning is dynamic params are the title and url when they has been updated

Comment: simply what i need is send the dynamic parameters to php file,.

Comment: do you have a data div for every pair of inputs or only one wrapping them all? also do you want to make the ajax call when either the url or the title changes?

Comment: @koala_dev i can add divs for every pair of inputs. i need what you are thinking!!!!

Comment: but do you only have one <div> for all your inputs? or do you have `<div id="data2">` etc.

Comment: @kola_dev i edit the code please check

Comment: by dynamic you mean that your elements are added after the page is loaded (i.e. with some button and js code) or are they generated server side?

Comment: @ kola_dev elements are added after the page loded from js code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#data1').on('change','[id^=title],[id^=url]',function(){

    var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('title',"").replace('url',"");

    var title = $("#title" + index).val();
    var url = $("#url" + index).val();
    var hid = $("#hid" + index).val();
    // you can put in here in sequence all the fields you have
    $.post('library/edit.php',{title:title, url:url, hid : hid},function(res){
        alert ("updated !");
    });
});

});
```

so by this answer if any text box whoes id starts with title changes.
the function passed in will be invoked.
indezx variable will store the index of the group of the elements that are changing. and then is being callculated by removing title from title1 or title2

Comment: hi Parv..would be please tell me what is the meaning of "^=" ?

Comment: its a wild card character and [id^=title] means all the elements whoes id attribute starts with title

Comment: hi @ParvSharma i need to pass the thress elements to the php file if any one changes in that div... i update the code plese help

Comment: what is this var index ??

Comment: title1 url1 hid1
title2 url2 hid2
title3 url3 hid3

Comment: no you dont need them and i think they were not present in your original question

Comment: @ParvSharma i need to call the php file if url1 changed also... did u het it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you have it right here:

> *I wrote that code to call to php file on change of textbox.*

That script (`jQuery` I guess) it must be associatte with the `$('#xxx1').onchange()` right? (or similar)
If you modify the function, add a class to the input field (also in the php) and each time you call the function, start listening again.. I think you can call any function you may want.

Example (guessing your code)

### HTML

```
<div id="data1" class="dynamicDiv">
  <input name="title1" type="text" id="title1" />
  <input name="url1" type="text" id="url1" />
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
// enable the function on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  startListening('.dynamicDiv');
});

// each time an ajax call is completed,
// run the function again to map new objects
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  startListening('.dynamicDiv');
});

// and finally the function
function startListening(obj){
  $(obj).onchange(function(){
    // ajax call
    // function call
    // or whatever...
  });
}
```

### PHP

```
// some code....
// some code....
// remember here to add "dynamicDiv" as a class in the object
return object;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your elements are dynamically generated you need to use event delegation, then you can use `[id^="value"]` to select the appropriate elements based on the first part of their id attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','[id^="data"]',function(){
        var title = $(this).find('[id^="title"]').val();
        var url = $(this).find('[id^="url"]').val();
        var hidden = $(this).find('[id^="hid"]').val();
        $.post('library/edit.php',{title:title, url:url, hid:hidden},function(res){
            alert ("updated !");
        });
    });
});
```

Note: I suggest you bind to the closest parent of your data divs that is present at page load instead of binding to the document

Comment: this will not work for elements being added dynamically and which are not present at the page load time

Comment: @kola_dev i need to pass a hidden value also how to do that?

Comment: @user2645118 did you try the code? I assumed your div ids are data1, data2, etc as in your first example, if they are div1, div2 then change the selector accordingly